# UITableViewCell does not have a member named nameLabel

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a custom cell for my tableView. I believe I followed all the correct steps but when I try to write code to access my custom properties from cellForRowAtIndexPath, I get the aforementioned error. It is as if it the custom properties cannot be seen.

Custom cell:

```
class MapViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var accessibleImage: UIImageView!
```

TableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as MapViewTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
```

I verified that the custom cell objects in the storyboard are connected to the MapViewTableViewCell outlets. I also verified that the custom cell in the storyboard has its class set as MapViewTableViewCell.

I am using XCode 6.1.1

I was wondering if anyone could shed some insight as to what might be going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line

```
var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as MapViewTableViewCell
```

you are forcing the cell to be of type `UITableViewCell` which indeed does not have a member `nameLabel`. Change this line to

```
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as MapViewTableViewCell
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help!